# Remove empty cells from pandas read_excel function

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an excel file using pandas and I'm creating a list of elements for each column.
I need to remove or better yet, not read the empty cells at all.

I've tried various combinations of arguments such as:

```
na_filter=True/False
keep_default_na=True/False
na_values=None
```

but none of them completely removes the empty cell but only, at best, replaces them with an empty string or **nan**

Now I'm using this method to do what I need:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', keep_default_na=False, sheet_name="Sheet1")
a_list = df['A'].tolist()
a_list = list(filter(('').__ne__, a_list))
b_list = df['B'].tolist()
b_list = list(filter(('').__ne__, b_list))
c_list = df['C'].tolist()
c_list = list(filter(('').__ne__, c_list))
```

that *manually* removes the empty list elements but I'm looking for a more pythonic way.

Comment: is the below answer suitable in your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dropna` to remove the row with null values from dataframe. Please refer below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
newdf = df.dropna()
```

There are few parameters which you can pass to `dropna` function based on your requirements.

```
dataframe.dropna(axis, how, thresh, subset, inplace)
```